# Selecting multiple items in list using setOnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onitemlongclicklistener

I have a list of messages in an Android listview. I want to delete the messages from the list on press of Long Click. I have declared all the states in my list-selector but still on long press. The particular item in the list does not remain focused or selected after long press. I tried setting the view.setselected(true), which isn't working either. Am I doing something wrong?

This is my list_selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/row_item_image" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/row_item_hover_image" />
<item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/row_item_hover_image" />
<item android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/row_item_hover_image" />
</selector>
```

And this is my listener interface:

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //view.setSelected(true);
        if(view.isPressed())
        {
        view.setSelected(true);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: but if you want to delete it why should it keeps the pressed/selected state?

Comment: multiple items from the list will be selected and then deleted at the same time..the same way we have nowadays in android phones..for example similar to what we see in HangOuts messaging app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don`t need to implement OnItemLongClickListener because ListView itself has such functionality what you want.Try this on your activity:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            editListAdapter.removeSelection();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete_action_mode, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete_mode:
                SparseBooleanArray selected = editListAdapter.getSelectedIds();
                for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                        User selectedItem = editListAdapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                        editListAdapter.remove(selectedItem);
                    }
                }
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id,
                boolean checked) {
            int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " selected");
            editListAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }
    });
```

Your ArrayAdapter Class would be like this:

```
public class UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

LayoutInflater inflater;
private int resId;
private TextView userPosition, userName, userLogin, userPassw, userStatus, userRole;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
private List<User> userList;

public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<User> users) {
    super(context, resource, users);
    this.resId = resource;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.userList = users;
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    User user = getItem(position);
    UserItemHelper helper;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resId, parent, false);
        userPosition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_item_position);
        userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_item_name);
        userLogin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_item_login);
        userPassw = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_item_passw);
        userStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_item_status);
        userRole = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_item_role);
        helper = new UserItemHelper(userPosition, userName, userLogin, userPassw, userStatus, userRole);
        convertView.setTag(helper);
    } else {
        helper = (UserItemHelper)convertView.getTag(); 
    }
    helper.getPosition().setText(position + 1 + "");
    helper.getName().setText(user.getName());
    helper.getLogin().setText(user.getLogin());
    helper.getPassw().setText(user.getPassw());
    helper.getStatus().setText(user.getStatus() +"");
    helper.getRole().setText(user.getRole()+"");
    return convertView;
}

public ArrayList<String> getItemsName() {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
        names.add(getItem(i).getName().toLowerCase());
    }
    return names;
}

@Override
public void remove(User object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.remove(object);
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;

}
```

}

Also create menu xml.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <item
         android:id="@+id/delete_mode"
         android:icon="@drawable/delete"
         android:title="@string/delete_text"/>

   </menu>
```